# Gerrit docker image admin operation using public key during the image creation

Tags: dockerfile, gerrit, public-key, ssh-keygen

i am trying to create a Docker image for gerrit so i need to add admin public within image so that no need add again from GUI , so to skip adding from GUI to do all admin operations( creating project and templates) i added below variables in the DOCKERFILE, but still it asking for public key when i try creatae a project any body aware of this ?

ENV GERRIT_PUBLIC_KEYS_PATH /var/gerrit/ssh-keys
ENV GERRIT_ADMIN_USER ca_zuul_qa

RUN mkdir -p /var/gerrit/ssh-keys
COPY key /var/gerrit/ssh-keys/id-admin-rsa.pub